# Why are parentheses significant in F# type declarations

Tags: types, f#, pattern-matching

I'm completely baffled by observing this behaviour in my F# code, here taken from an interactive session:

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> type foo = Foo of (string * int);;
  type foo = | Foo of (string * int)

> let f = Foo ("bar",42);;
  val f : foo = Foo ("bar", 42)

> match f with Foo x -> x;;
  val it : string * int = ("bar", 42)

> type bar = Bar of string * int;;
  type bar = | Bar of string * int

> let b = Bar ("baz",21);;
  val b : bar = Bar ("baz",21)

> match b with Bar x -> x;;
  match b with Bar x -> x;;
  -------------^^^^^

stdin(7,14): error FS0019: This constructor is applied to 1 argument(s) but expects 2
>
```

It seems obvious to me that pattern matching on both Foo and Bar with a single variable should be valid - so I was wondering if anyone knew the reason for this wierd behaviour, or if you like me consider it a bug.

Update:
Just to clarify, the reported types of the constructors `Foo` and `Bar` are:

```
> Foo;;
val it : string * int -> foo = <fun:clo@14-1>
> Bar;;
val it : string * int -> bar = <fun:clo@13>
```

So certainly, they should accept the same set of valid patterns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree this looks quite confusing. As pad explained, the difference between the two declarations is not just syntactical - you are actually defining discriminated union cases that consist of different types.

- In case of `Foo`, the case contains one element of type `int * string`
- In case of `Bar`, the case contains two elements of type `int` and `string`

The two options are very similar, but they are actually different. You can see that if you look at [the type definitions in the F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc321997149). Here are the bits that describe type definitions of discriminated union:

> union-type-defn :=
>        type-name '=' union-type-cases type-extension-elements<sub>opt</sub>
>
> union-type-cases :=
>      '|'<sub>opt</sub>  union-type-case '|' ... '|' union-type-case
>
> union-type-case :=
>       attributes<sub>opt</sub>   union-type-case-data
>
> union-type-case-data :=
>       ident                                    -- null union case
>       ident of type * ... * type      -- n-ary union case

Note that the "n-ary union case" consists of multiple elements (`type * ... * type`). A *type* is defined as follows (not surprisingly, it can be a tuple):

> type :=
>         ( type )
>         type -> type              -- function type
>       type * ... * type     -- tuple type
>      ...                         -- lots of other types

I do not know why *union-type-case-data* does not use just unary union case (instead of n-ary) and always treat the elements as tuple. I think that would make perfect sense, but it might be something that F# inherited from OCaml or ML. However, at least the specification explains this!

In fact, I suppose the specification is a bit ambiguous, because you could treat `Foo of int * int` as both n-ary union case and unary case with a tuple (but without the bracketted type `( type )`).

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough reply, even pointing out the relevant piece of the language specification! But I'm afraid that I consider it even more a grave monstrosity now, nowing that it was intentional! :-)

Comment: @plc - I'd speculate that the reason for the difference is to control the interop boundary with other languages like C#.  In that case you might care if you need to create a DU instance by passing in a pre-constructed tuple or by passing in the constituent items individually.